# How to set validation in DOM Parser

Tags: xml, dom, xml-parsing

I am using DOM parser I am trying to set validation.Accoring to [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#setValidating%28boolean%29) of DOMBuilderFactory if I setValidating to true I am not able to understand on what it will validate?Can some one help me understanding this?

```
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory: factory.setValidating(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will validate against a given schema or DTD.

Given the following for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">
   <foo></foo>
 </beans>
```

It's a well-formed XML, if you don't set validate to true, the document will be parsed.

If however, you will set validate to true, the document structure will be validated against
`spring-beans-3.2.xsd` schema which doesn't allow the `foo` element. The parser (document builder) will throw a `SAXParseException` in this case.

An XML schema describes what elements and attributes allowed in the document, data types, order of elements, number of occurrences etc. This schema allows `bean` elements nested inside `beans`, for example.